# Как мне получить числа 215, 248, 252 из Json

Tags: android, json

Я знаю что в Json data 30 объектов. Как мне получить числа 215, 248, 252 и т.д. не зная изначально их. Если бы они были в массиве то я бы мог указать типо 0 1 2 3 4 5....

```
{
"status":"success",
   "data":{
     "215":{},
     "248":{},
     "252":{},
     "267":{
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как вы хотите стандартными средствами никак, разве что вручную пройтись по ключам объекта, достать значения по этим ключам и сложить их в массив. Но порядок в `JsonObject` не гарантируется. `JsonArray` состоит только из значений, а не из пар ключ-значение. Описание `json` формата можно посмотреть здесь - http://www.json.org/json-ru.html, возможно многое станет понятно.

Если это вы контролируете создание json, то можно привести к такому виду:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "A1": {
        "key1": 123
      }
    },
    {
      "A2": {
        "key2": 456
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Тогда `data` можно преобразовать в `JsonArray` и можно будет получать значения по индексу.

**UPD:**
Для получение только ключей можно сделать так:

```
JSONObject jsonObject;
//получаем jsonObject 
JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
for(Iterator<String> keys = dataObject.keys(); keys.hasNext(); ) {
    String key = keys.next();
    // что-то делаем с ключом
}
```

Comment: А можно ли самому создать тогда?

Тобишь взять все объекты из data и поместить из в array?

Comment: @xTIGRx у JSONObject есть метод ```keys()```, который можно использовать для получения всех ключей в объекте и потом по ключам получить значение, но я надеюсь вы понимаете что в JSONArray вы не добавите их в формате в котором хотите. Ну и вообще, странно присылать ```json``` с динамическими ключами. На то они и ключи, что должны быть постоянными.

Comment: Меня тут осенило и я вопрос обновил гляньте плиз, можете ответ свой переделать под вопрос? думаю вы поймете что я хочу именно)